# Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 - multiple "orderers" for single channel

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

The network configuration that is provided with the e2e_cli example has only one "orderer" container and a set of kafka/zookeeper containers.

My questions are:

- Q1: Is the single "orderer" some kind of architectural restriction of
  HLFv1.0 when single channel need to be created ?
- Q2: Is it possible
  to run multiple "orderers" for HA purposes when only one channel is
  used ?

the documentation suggests that multiple orderers can be used,  but my understanding is that each "orderer" provide ordering service for single channel - is it right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Q1: Is the single "orderer" some kind of architectural restriction of
>   HLFv1.0 when single channel need to be created ?

No, you can have more than 1 ordering service node.

> Q2: Is it possible to run multiple "orderers" for HA purposes when
>   only one channel is used ?

Yes. That was the intention of the kafka-based orderer - to have multiple instances of ordering service nodes all connect to a single fault tolerant service (kafka) that would do the ordering, and have them act as mediators to that service.

> the documentation suggests that multiple orderers can be used, but my
>   understanding is that each "orderer" provide ordering service for
>   single channel - is it right ?

You can submit a transaction or pull a block from any of the orderers.
They would go to the same kafka node that is the leader of that channel for that time.
Also - orderers are multi-tenant regarding channels - orderers can service multiple channels.

Comment: In case of Kafka-based ordered, if the orderer container is paused, do we still be able to do transactions? I am assuming it to be single fault tolerance service.